# Fixed header disapearing on ios safari bounce

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Current results:

[image]

Expected results:

[image]

You can see an actual example here if you have an iOS device: client.wildfyre.net

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
    #topNav {
      height: 50px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #263238;
      color: white;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 5;
    }

    #topNavMenu {
      position: fixed;
      right: -20px;
      top: 7px;
    }
```

Comment: your example requires login credentials

Comment: You dont need to login to see the bug, the header is at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should understand what is causing the problem.

[image]

If you remove the 'mat-drawer-content' class and the transition inline styles, then you will get rid of the scrolling effect.

Now, if you want the scrolling effect and don't want to see this issue, then we have 2 solutions:

1. Remove `<nav>` as a child of `'mat-drawer-content'` div and add as a sibling, so that the transition effect is not applied on the `<nav>` tag.

or

2. Add an `overflow: hidden` property on the `'mat-drawer-content'`.
   [image]

I tried both of them on the real device and it works.
Attached Screenshot from iphoneX.
[image]

Comment: I only have an iPhone on safari,  how do you debug? I don't have this class but I have the exact same bounce effect at the top.

Comment: Well you can connect your iphone with Mac and debug it from there. There are many articles over the internet, try this:  https://appletoolbox.com/use-web-inspector-debug-mobile-safari/

Answer (score 0):

I have debugged it and the only solution that i figure out is you have to move the `nav` tag for sure including what inside it and **don't move the other nav tags** like that so the red ones leave them as it is and the blue one move it up

[image]

```
<nav aria-label="Navigation links" class="mat-tab-nav-bar mat-primary" id="topNav" md-tab-nav-bar=""></nav>
```

outside from that div

```
<div cdk-scrollable="" class="mat-drawer-content" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
```

once the `nav` tag outside that div `class="mat-drawer-content"` everything will be fine because this `class="mat-drawer-content"` when you scroll it moves the whole component and thats cause this issue

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is the css `overflow` property for the class `.mat-drawer-content`; just remove the `overflow: auto;` from that class or set it to `hidden`, and the bug will be gone in Safari iOS. I also tested in other browser and platforms, and removing that property doesn't seems to affect anything else.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Does that happens on the login page too? Can i reproduce the bug there?

Comment: I tested it in a real iphone plugged to my Mac. Thats why i posted the solution. Let me do a screenshot for you @CameronGilbert